# Google Analytics Reporting API returning empty object - NodeJs

Tags: json, node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-nodejs-client

first question so bear with me.

I am using NodeJS to query the Google Analytics Reporting API. I am able to receive the OAuth 2 token I need, and when I query the API I get a 200 response back.  However the payload that returns is an empty object instead of the JSON formatted report response that is the intended goal.

```
var https = require('https');
var google = require('googleapis');
var key = require('path/to/key');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email,null,key.private_key,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',null);

var getGoogleData = google.analyticsreporting('v4');

var googleTemplates = {"reportRequests":[{"viewId": "######","dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2014-11-01", "endDate": "2014-11-30"}],"metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"},{"expression": "ga:newUsers"},{"expression": "ga:pageviews / ga:sessions"}]},{"viewId": "######","dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2014-11-01", "endDate": "2014-11-30"}],"metrics": [{"expression": "ga:transactionRevenue"},{"expression": "ga:transactions"},{"expression":"ga:transactions / ga:sessions"},{"expression":"ga:revenuePerTransaction"}]}]};
var googleToken={};


var requestReport = function(reportRequest,token){


    reportRequest = JSON.stringify(reportRequest);
    //console.log(reportRequest);

    var requestObject = {
        method:'POST',
        hostname:'analyticsreporting.googleapis.com',
        path:'/v4/reports:batchGet',
        headers:{
            Accept:'*/*',
            Authorization:'Bearer '+token.access_token,
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

    var callbackGoogle = function(response){
        console.log('\n-----------------------\n');
        console.log('Requesting Report : Google Analytics\nStatus Code: [', response.statusCode +': '+ response.statusMessage+']');
        console.log('-----------------------\n\n');

        var data = [];

        response.on('data',function(chunk){
            data.push(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end',function(){
            var buff = new Buffer(data.join('')).toString();

            console.log('////////////////////////// Success //////////////////////////\n')
            console.log(buff);

        });

        response.on('error',function(e){
            console.log(e);
        });
    };

    var req = https.request(requestObject,callbackGoogle);
    req.on('error',function(e){
            console.log('requestReport Error:\n',e);
        });
    req.write(reportRequest);
    req.end();

};

(function googleAccess(){
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err,tokens){
        console.log('\n-----------------------\n');
        console.log('Authenticate: Google \n');

        if(err){
            console.log('Google Error',err);
            return;
        }

        googleToken = tokens;

        requestReport(googleTemplates,tokens);

        console.log('Success: true');
        console.log('\n-----------------------\n\n');
    })
})();
```

The console output is as follows:

```
-----------------------

Authenticate: Google 

Success: true

-----------------------

-----------------------

Requesting Report : Google Analytics
Status Code: [ 200: OK]
-----------------------

////////////////////////// Success //////////////////////////

{}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why the payload is returning as an empty object? It *should* be a report JSON file.

Comment: You should try just `console.log(response);` to see the entire output. It appears you've installed the google apis and even have the analyticsreporting service object (`getGoogleData` in your code) but you are not using it; is there a reason?

Comment: I did actually try that. I can post the whole response object Monday.

The reason I am not using the analyticsreporting service object is that the documentation on it was sparse, and I was somewhat confused as to what the attached method `getGoogleData.reports.batchGet()` was expecting to have passed into it. I decided to try the process manually, but only after I tried the method batchGet first. When I do use the methods attached to the service I receive a 'NULL' response, and Google logs 401 and 403 errors or nothing. Information on the batchGet method would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: More examples: The [samples page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#dimensions_and_metrics) are written with the default javascript library. are written in the `serviceobject.method(requestbody).execute(callbackmethod)` format, the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js) is written with [promoses](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises#using-promises), aslo using the service object.

Comment: If the default method is returning `403` or `401` it could either be because Auth is set up incorrectly or that you are using the wrong `viewID`. These are just the two most popular errors but it is equally possible that your there is something wrong with your requests. from your template above you are attempting to make two requests in one batch get. I'd first debug getting a single request working and then add extra `reportRequest` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! File this one under 'not seeing the forest for the trees'.

The `requestObject` should have `'Content-type':'application/json'`.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the node js sdk from google?

Comment: This task involved integrating data from Google Analytics and Adobe Analytics. Ultimately I did use a library from Google, but I as I recall I had to do some data packaging gymnastics to get the project dashboard to display both data sources together.